# Simple POST form error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Newbie to Laravel, trying to make a form that uses POST to send a single parameter. I want to query a DB table for last names using the first name I input in the form.

I think I narrowed down the error to either my route:

```
Route::post('get_last', function()
{
    $query= 'SELECT last FROM "names" WHERE first =?';
    $bindings= array(Input::post('first_name'));
    $last_name = Name::selectOne($query, $bindings);

    Redirect::route('last_name', array('last_name' => $last_name));
});
```

The redirect is a page that is supposed to show the results, I tested that one manually and it seems to work. I believe the error could also be something in the blade file though:

```
@extends('layout')

@section('content')
  {{ Form::open(array('url' => 'get_last', 'method' => 'POST')) }}

    {{ Form::text('first_name', 'First Name') }}

    {{ Form::submit('Search') }}

  {{ Form::close() }}

@stop
```

For reference this is the exception I get when I run it:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)

Call to undefined method Illuminate\Http\Request::post()
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `Input::get()` instead of `Input::post()`

The keyword get in Input facade is not bound to $_GET but it's the name of the getter method.